# error shown in flutter native splash screen importing doest work

Tags: flutter, splash-screen

i have an error in initState importing doesnt package doesnt work

[error in flutter native splash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlrCi.png)

Answer (score 0):

Did you imported the package using **import** at the top? if so then check the version compatibility of package with your flutter version. If you've just added this package, try **flutter clean** and **flutter pub get**.

Comment: yes i ve imported it and i have also added it

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Show()` method on Flutter Native Splash.  I advice reading the [instructions](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash) on how to use the package.